How can we shorten the delay when resetting the Apple ID password?
My daughter forgot her Apple ID password. We started the process of resetting from her iPad (her only apple device). They sent a code to her e-mail, and another one to my telephone (trusted phone number). We correctly confirmed both codes.
We received a message that in 24h they would send an e-mail saying how long she has to wait to change the password. Why is that and how to expedite that?

Why: To make it hard to use a stolen device and so deter thieves.

This is by design and intended to protect you daughter’s iPad and data.
As Apple states on their “How to use account recovery when you can’t reset your Apple ID password” page:

“For security reasons, it might take several days or longer before you can use your account again. We know this delay is inconvenient, but it's important so that we can keep your account and information safe.”

As far as “speeding things up” go, the fine print on that same page reads:

“In some cases, you might be able to speed up the account recovery process or reset your password immediately by verifying a six-digit code sent to your primary email address. You might also be able to shorten the wait time by providing credit-card details to confirm your identity. If you’re given this option, an authorization request goes to the card issuer.”

They also have a way to check the status of you request as explained on that page:

“At any time, you can see how long it will be until your account is ready for recovery, or when more information will be available. Just go to iforgot.apple.com and enter your Apple ID.”

